# How to build a form with multiple properties (using IEnumerable or multiple properties in the class) when data ain't already exist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I'm confused about how I have to build my Model class and the form. To work with two (has the possibility to be more in the future) properties with the same type. I think it's more obviously to use an IEnumerable but when comes to put into a form to work with I can't get a way to do this.

The main idea is to have a student form, where I can define two teachers (math and biology for example) to the student.
*Note that I need to always create new teachers for each student, with specific subject and classroom. Not loaded/already created ones.

```
public class Student
{
   // other properties like Id, Name
   public Teacher MathTeacher { get; set; }
   public Teacher BiologyTeacher { get; set; }

   // or

   public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; } 
}

public class Teacher
{
   // other properties like Id, Name
   public int SubjectId { get; set; }
   public int ClassroomId { get; set; }
}
```

But if I use the two properties I believe Entity Framework can't know the exactly teacher to get after this. So, how can I use the IEnumerable property to read the data from a form like this:

in all `<select>`s should I use `asp-for="???"` or which is the right way?

```
<h6>Math Teacher</h6>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <label class="form-label">Subject</label>
    <select class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Subjects, "Id", "Name"))">
        <option disabled selected>Select the subject</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <label class="form-label">Classroom</label>
    <select class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Classrooms, "Id", "Name"))">
        <option disabled selected>Select the classroom</option>
    </select>
</div>

<h6>Biology Teacher</h6>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <label class="form-label">Subject</label>
    <select class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Subjects, "Id", "Name"))">
        <option disabled selected>Select the subject</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <label class="form-label">Classroom</label>
    <select class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Classrooms, "Id", "Name"))">
        <option disabled selected>Select the classroom</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I want to get a model loaded like this after submit the form:

student:

- id: 3
- name: 'aaaaa'
- teachers:

  - id 1, name: 'xxxx', subjectId: 3, classroomId: 1,
  - id 3, name: 'zzzz', subjectId: 54, classroomId: 1

or with the purpose of two properties?

student:

- id: 3
- name: 'aaaaa'
- mathTeacher: id 1, name: 'xxxx', subjectId: 3, classroomId: 1,
- biologyTeacher: id 3, name: 'zzzz', subjectId: 54, classroomId: 1

I just can't get any example of how get something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But if I use the two properties I believe Entity Framework can't know the exactly teacher to get after this

Two properties can be bound and distinguish successfully actually.

Here is a working demo you could follow:

Model

```
public class Student
{
    // other properties like Id, Name
    public Teacher MathTeacher { get; set; }
    public Teacher BiologyTeacher { get; set; }

    public List<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public List<Classroom> Classrooms { get; set; }
}
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Classroom
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Teacher
{
    // other properties like Id, Name
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public int ClassroomId { get; set; }
}
```

View(Create.cshtml)

```
@model Student
<h6>Math Teacher</h6>
<form method="post" asp-action="Create">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <label class="form-label">Subject</label>
        <select class="form-select" asp-for="MathTeacher.SubjectId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Subjects, "Id", "Name"))">
            <option disabled selected>Select the subject</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <label class="form-label">Classroom</label>
        <select class="form-select" asp-for="MathTeacher.ClassroomId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Classrooms, "Id", "Name"))">
            <option disabled selected>Select the classroom</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <h6>Biology Teacher</h6>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <label class="form-label">Subject</label>
        <select class="form-select" asp-for="BiologyTeacher.SubjectId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Subjects, "Id", "Name"))">
            <option disabled selected>Select the subject</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <label class="form-label">Classroom</label>
        <select class="form-select" asp-for="BiologyTeacher.ClassroomId" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Classrooms, "Id", "Name"))">
            <option disabled selected>Select the classroom</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
```

Controller

**Note:** Hard-coded the data here for easy testing, you can get the data from database by yourself.

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()
{
    //hard-coded for easy testing....
    //set the value for the selectlist
    var model = new Student()
    {
        Subjects = new List<Subject>()
        {
            new Subject(){Id=1,Name="sub1"},
            new Subject(){Id=2,Name="sub2"},
            new Subject(){Id=3,Name="sub3"}
        },
        Classrooms = new List<Classroom>()
        {
            new Classroom(){Id=1,Name="room1"},
            new Classroom(){Id=2,Name="room2"},
            new Classroom(){Id=3,Name="room3"}
        }
    };
    return View(model); 
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Student model)
{
    //do your stuff....
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, really. But, unfortunately I made a mistake about my real example, if we just ignore the Classroom property and work with more Subject <select>s items.
I have in my Teacher model an IEnumerable property called Subjects, and each <select> have to aim to Student.MathTeacher.Subjects, three times. I used your answer with my "new" logic of how things need to be, but in the action the model still with all properties `null`.
Something like this, three times for each teacher
<select asp-for="Model.MathTeacher.Subjects" asp-items="Subjects..."></select>

Comment: If I exaggerated with that, I can edit/make another question

Comment: My database tables schema needs to be something like
`Students (Id, Name)`
`Teachers (StudentId, TeacherId) (always new created ones)`
`Teacher_Subject (TeacherId, SubjectId)`

With Entity now trying to figure out what I need to do, I think these two properties of the same type (`MathTeacher` and `BiologyTeacher`) wouldn't be work for me.

Comment: Does this makes sense? `Student.Teachers[0].Subjects[0].SubjectId` `Student.Teachers[0].Subjects[1].SubjectId` and the last one `Student.Teachers[0].Subjects[2].SubjectId `

Now I can get the the three subjects for each teacher in the teacher collections in the student. But it seems to be a poor solution to manually have to put the indexes

Comment: `<select asp-for="Model.MathTeacher.Subjects" asp-items="Subjects..."></select>` This is not correct, selectlist need match the simple type data instead of model or list model.  And I think you may not be clearly explain your requirement, e.g if your Student has many Classrooms and Subjects, you need create two multiple select dropdown. I think what you need to do is to explain these tables' relationship.

Comment: And do not mix all the thing together, if you just want to create a Student, you can put the Subjects, Classrooms and Teachers with multiple select dropdown, For the teacher if it also contain Subject and Classrooms, you need put another different multiple select dropdown, so firstly you need clearly explain what you want. Because if just for coding requirement, my code correctly told you how model binding works.

Comment: I get it about the select `asp-for`, thanks. I tried to make another question explaining my tables layout too https://stackoverflow.com/q/74365044/15845289. If you can give a try to it, I'll be glad.