# How to build a form and model with multiple properties with same object type? Collection property or "n" properties for each one?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to build a model to respect the following database schema:

[image: Database schema]

And I have the current models:

```
public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
    }

public class Subject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<TeacherSubject> Teachers { get; set; }
    }

public class Teacher
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<TeacherSubject> Subjects { get; set; }
        public Student Student { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
    }

public class TeacherSubject
    {
        public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
        public int TeacherId { get; set; }
        public Subject Subject { get; set; }
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    }
```

My View Model:

```
public class StudentFormViewModel
    {
        public Student Student { get; set; }
        public SelectList Subjects { get; set; }
    }
```

My View:

```
@model StudentFormViewModel

<form asp-action="Create">
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input asp-for="Student.Name" />
    </div>
    <h3>Biology Teacher</h3>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label>Subject 1</label>
        <select class="form-select" asp-for="Student.Teachers[0].Subjects[0].SubjectId" asp-items="Model.Subjects">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label>Subject 2</label>
        <select class="form-select" asp-for="Student.Teachers[0].Subjects[1].SubjectId" asp-items="Model.Subjects">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label>Subject 3</label>
        <select class="form-select" asp-for="Student.Teachers[0].Subjects[2].SubjectId" asp-items="Model.Subjects">
        </select>
    </div>

    <h3>Math Teacher</h3>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label>Subject 1</label>
        <select class="form-select" asp-for="Student.Teachers[1].Subjects[0].SubjectId" asp-items="Model.Subjects">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label>Subject 2</label>
        <select class="form-select" asp-for="Student.Teachers[1].Subjects[1].SubjectId" asp-items="Model.Subjects">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <label>Subject 3</label>
        <select class="form-select" asp-for="Student.Teachers[1].Subjects[1].SubjectId" asp-items="Model.Subjects">
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This way I can achive the model binding to each teacher and subject selected. 
But I want to set the Name property of Teacher, to know if is "Math" or "Biology" **to insert correctly in database and when load these form to update, I can know which select I have to fill with Math or Biology subjects**.

Should I use two properties into Student referring the Teachers? something like this:

```
public Teacher MathTeacher { get; set; }
public Teacher BiologyTeacher { get; set; }
```

My desired output is something like this:

```
{
    name: 'student a',
    teachers: [
        {
            name: 'Math',
            subjectIds: [1, 2, 3]
        },
        {
            name: 'Biology',
            subjectIds: [1, 5, 32]
            // or
            subjects: [
                { id: 1 },
                { id: 5 },
                { id: 32 }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

{
    name: 'student a',
    mathTeacher: {
        name: 'Math',
        subjectIds: [1, 2, 3]
    },
    biologyTeacher: {
        name: 'Biology',
        subjectIds: [1, 5, 32]
        // or
        subjects: [
            { id: 1 },
            { id: 5 },
            { id: 32 }
        ]
    }
    
}
```

I'm stuck at this and can't figure out how to implement this form/model to entity situation

Comment: It helps to think of the relationships between the tables first... whether it's one-to-one, one-to-many, or many-to-many.  Not sure I understand why TeacherSubject is there.  Doesn't seem like that's necessary.   Instead you'd have a many-to-many between teacher and subject?  (if a teacher can have more than one subject)  You'd then make you view model match the information you need for the form.

Comment: TeacherSubject exists because I have a many-to-many relationship (TeacherSubject table)? And to build a table like this in Entity I have to configure using this class for relationship.
Because I have the Student. And this Student will have Teacher(s) (always new ones). And this Teacher can have many Subjects. (But I have specific ones in this form, like Math and Biology as I said), but I will use this in other part of my program. I will have other kind of Teacher (Physics for example), and I want to have all Teachers Subjects in one single table.

Comment: I'm just wondering if I just put a hidden field to set the property name already declared to the value I want, "Math", "Biology" and so on.

Comment: And about the relationship, it is kinda not so difficult. The problem is adapting to a form.

Comment: ahh k,... I tend to go with the ids only instead of the lists... seems like you'd also have many-to-many for students<->teachers.  The number of classes/subjects might not be the same for every student, so you might want to have an "Add Class/Subject" button that will add each one.  Then build the selectlist's accordingly.  public List<SelectListItem> SubjectTeacherSelectItems; in your view model.   Ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579598/c-sharp-mvc-3-using-selectlist-with-selected-value-in-view You'd find all the teachers who teach that subject and add to the select list.

Comment: So another table for "Classes"... each class has a teacher and a subject.  Each student has one-to-many relationship with classes.   This keeps things much simpler because you'll have a student with x number of classes, and each class has a one-to-one with teacher and subject.  (and you can have different times/location for the "classes" you build too)  This would allow you to remove some many-to-many relationships if they aren't needed.

Comment: Also see MS's tutorial which seems very relevant to what you are doing here.. (they create a "Contoso University":  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I think this is out of the scope of the real problem, putting a new class "Class". I know the logic of my application sounds weird, like always creating a new teacher instead of loading existing ones to select to a new student for example. But it's not the case, I really need to create new ones for each new student.

Comment: Imagine a Task class. A task contains some steps, in the second step I have a class to represent it too. This step has two properties (or the collection that I want to know how to proceed) representing a risk. We have controled risk and pure risk.
But in third step (another class) I have total risk. So, I want to be able to have all risks in one table only. But I can't figure out how to manage the models and the view (form) to handle that.

Comment: It helps to draw out a diagram of the DB, tables and their relationships.  The structure of the data.  Then think about what views of that data you need, and the steps it would take on the GUI side to create the records.  If you need a new teacher for each student, then you can eliminate the teacher table.  Just add those teacher fields/properties as properties of Student.